# How to prevent a process to run?

Tags: process

I want some process not to run because I don't need them. Is there a way to prevent from running some processes?

After start up if possible or by opening applications with is it "child process" (i mean under).

Comment: If they are processes run at start-up, they can be disabled, if you really need them to be.  Do you have any examples?

Answer (score 0):

You can stop the process from running by changing the permissions.

Look for the process and remove the execute permission.

use `-x` option with `chmod` command to remove the execute permission.

Be sure of what you are doing. Few process might depend on other process. So make sure what you stopping.